# How to add users to Apache Ranger via REST API

Tags: apache, hadoop, policy, apache-ranger

As in the title, how to manually add a user to Apache Ranger via REST API.

Could you post an example of curl call?

Could you post in addiction an url where i can find the docs for:

```
   http:<ip>:6080/service/xusers/???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Global note for all queries: Sometimes you have to remove /secure

**Get a User**

```
curl -u admin:admin -v -i -s -X GET http://xxx:6080/service/xusers/secure/users/$ID_USER
```

Replace $ID_USER by your userId

- Note: Sometimes you have to remove /secure

**Get all User**

```
curl -u admin:admin -v -i -s -X GET http://xxx:6080/service/xusers/secure/users
```

**Delete a User**

```
curl -u admin:admin -v -i -s -X DELETE http://xxx:6080/service/xusers/secure/users/$ID_USER
```

Replace $ID_USER by your userId

**Add/POST a User**

```
curl -u admin:admin -v -i -s -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://xxx:6080/service/xusers/secure/users -d @userfile.json
```

- Note: Sometimes you have to remove /secure
- Note 2: userfile.json should be like this:

`{ "name":"user1",
  "firstName":"user1",
  "lastName": "user1",
  "loginId": "user1",
  "emailAddress" : null,
  "description" : "user1 desc",
  "password" : "user1pass",
  "groupIdList":[2,12],
  "status":1,
  "isVisible":1,
  "userRoleList": [ "ROLE_SYS_ADMIN" ],
  "userSource": 0
}`

- userRoleList can be "ROLE_SYS_ADMIN" Or "ROLE_USER"
- If you remove password, the user will be an external user.

Comment: I am trying to create users and I just used the same json from above. The user creation succeeds, however, the user does not have the `firstName`(it's empty) and the values for `userRoleList`, `groupIdList` doesn't seem to reflect the same values that I gave in the json. I also tried using `groupNameList` and that doesn't seem to have any effect either. When I do a `GET` using the userID I got, it returns an `XML` without `password` field.I am also not able to delete the user I created using the `DELETE` or by using the web UI, the error message I see is `no user found with id`. Help please!

Comment: This is working fine for me but when I remove the password, it is showing **Password cannot be blank/null (INVALID PASSWORD)**. How can I create an external user with a rest API?

Comment: You can create a user with `/users/external` in your path for example `http://localhost:6080/service/xusers/users/external`.... See https://github.com/apache/ranger/blob/master/security-admin/src/main/java/org/apache/ranger/rest/XUserREST.java#L312

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to @lisztomania's answer that this page from the mailing list archive of Apache Ranger gives a lot of available API calls and their description. You can find there the API calls to add / delete a user / group :

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ranger.incubator.apache.org/msg00064.html

Hope it will help !